# why eclipse shows error The Application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again in a class InputMethodManager?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a problem with my Android application. I want to run project with InputMethodManager class, but Eclipse show me error **The Application has stopped unexpectedly**.

I don't use any method's, only create instance of InputMethodManager. I don't know what's wrong.

My code:

```
private static InputMethodManager inputMethodManager;

private static EditText editText;

private static String stringInstance;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_input_method_manager);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

}
```

My error log:

```
06-27 16:03:11.631: E/PhonePolicy(32): Could not preload class for phone policy: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback
06-27 16:03:26.411: E/BatteryService(80): usbOnlinePath not found
06-27 16:03:26.411: E/BatteryService(80): batteryVoltagePath not found
06-27 16:03:26.411: E/BatteryService(80): batteryTemperaturePath not found
06-27 16:03:30.851: E/EventHub(80): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
06-27 16:03:30.851: E/EventHub(80): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
06-27 16:03:31.082: E/WifiService(80): Invoking mWifiStateMachine.setWifiEnabled
06-27 16:03:32.541: E/ThrottleService(80): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
06-27 16:03:32.551: E/NetworkTimeUpdateService(80): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
06-27 16:03:32.551: E/NetworkTimeUpdateService(80): NTP server address not found, not syncing to NTP time
06-27 16:03:33.342: E/logwrapper(161): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
06-27 16:03:33.421: E/logwrapper(162): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
06-27 16:03:33.451: E/logwrapper(163): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
06-27 16:03:43.192: E/SoundPool(80): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
06-27 16:03:43.192: E/SoundPool(80): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
06-27 16:03:43.202: E/SoundPool(80): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
06-27 16:03:43.202: E/SoundPool(80): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
06-27 16:03:43.212: E/SoundPool(80): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
06-27 16:03:43.262: E/SoundPool(80): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
06-27 16:03:43.272: E/SoundPool(80): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
06-27 16:03:43.322: E/SoundPool(80): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
06-27 16:03:43.332: E/SoundPool(80): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
06-27 16:03:43.542: E/TelephonyManager(80): Hidden constructor called more than once per process!
06-27 16:03:43.542: E/TelephonyManager(80): Original: android, new: android
06-27 16:03:59.692: E/AndroidRuntime(378): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-27 16:03:59.692: E/AndroidRuntime(378): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.imm/com.example.imm.InputMethodManager}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager cannot be cast to com.example.imm.InputMethodManager
06-27 16:03:59.692: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1748)
06-27 16:03:59.692: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1764)
06-27 16:03:59.692: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
06-27 16:03:59.692: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1002)
06-27 16:03:59.692: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-27 16:03:59.692: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
06-27 16:03:59.692: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
06-27 16:03:59.692: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-27 16:03:59.692: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
06-27 16:03:59.692: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
06-27 16:03:59.692: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
06-27 16:03:59.692: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-27 16:03:59.692: E/AndroidRuntime(378): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager cannot be cast to com.example.imm.InputMethodManager
06-27 16:03:59.692: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at com.example.imm.InputMethodManager.onCreate(InputMethodManager.java:35)
06-27 16:03:59.692: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
06-27 16:03:59.692: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1712)
06-27 16:03:59.692: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  ... 11 more
: E/(): Device disconnected
```

Answer (score 0):

You imported the wrong InputMethodManager class, look at your exception :

`Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{com.example.imm/com.example.imm.InputMethodManager}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager cannot be cast to com.example.imm.InputMethodManager`

Just change the `import com.example.imm.InputMethodManager;` to `import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;` in the top of your java file.

Comment: If I do import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager Eclipse view 2 options next to this import: Remove unused import and Organize imports.